# How do I assign a value to a constant before plotting, without affecting other plots?

Tags: plotting

I would like to Plot and equation on a single chart, with this equation taking multiple forms because I set the value of a constant differently in each case.

The way I am doing it now seems too cumbersome; I create copies of the equation and manually substitute the specified value for the constant.

In my attempt to ease the work and shorten my code considerably, I tried something like the following, but with error:

```
With[y = 0.5, Plot[x^2 + y, {x, 0, 1}]]
```

What is the correct approach to this kind of problem?

Comment: `With[{y = 0.5}, Plot[x^2 + y, {x, 0, 1}]`? `With` takes a `List` as its first argument.

Answer (score 1):

```
Plot[
 Evaluate@Table[Tooltip[x^2 + y], {y, 0, 2, 1/2}],
 {x, 0, 1},
 PlotLegends -> (StringForm["y = ``", #] & /@ Range[0, 2, 1/2])]
```

[image]